# postfix dies misteriously... What logfiles and and debug flags should I look at to get a clue?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I'm stumped on this one... the process just dies, and leaves nothing particularly revealing in /var/log/mail.log

Answer (score 1):

If it crashes, there might be nothing in `/var/log/mail.log` but there might be things in `/var/log/mail.err`, did you look there?

You could also try launching postfix manually with the `-D` flag to see if there's any interesting debug output.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in */var/log/messages* or */var/log/syslog* around the time of failure?

Without more details of exploration it could be anything from the out-of-memory (oom)-killer stopping the process, to logrotate not restarting the service.

Answer (score 0):

I **[once](http://blog.sybreon.com/index.php/2008/07/strace-to-the-rescue/)** had a mysterious problem with *postfix* and it turned out to be due to a misconfigured DNS setting. This is probably not your problem but you can try to use `strace` to help you debug any mysterious problems.